# Why changing the catcode of : cause epsfbox to fail?

Tags: plain-tex, eps, metapost

I have the following very simple TeX file:

```
\input epsf

\catcode`\:=\active\def:{\thinspace\string:}

a: b

\centerline{\epsfbox{test.1}}

\bye
```

with `test.mp` containing

```
beginfig(1);
draw (0,0) -- (100,0);
endfig;

end;
```

When changing the catcode of `?`, `!`, etc. (as prescribed by French typographical rules), everything looks fine.
But for `:` specifically, the figure goes to a very weird place in the page.

Comment: Not really a solution, but if you're willing to use (Plain) LuaTeX, you can bypass the whole problem and use `luamplib`. This lets you input the MetaPost file and produce a PDF all with a single `luatex` compile instead of needing `mpost`, `tex`, `dvips`, and `ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\epsfbox` macro reads the header of the given PostScript file in order to get the BoundingBox values. You can look to the test.1 file to the first two lines:

```
%!PS
%%BoundingBox: -1 -1 101 1
```

Do you see the `:` here? This line is read with active `:` and the unhappiness is done. You can modify your code:

```
\centerline{\catcode`\:=12 \epsfbox{test.1}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to update `\dospecials`, that contains the list of characters that need changing their catcode in verbatim contexts. This is because the routine of `epsf.tex` for finding the bounding box information scans the file and expects standard category codes, so it uses `\dospecials` to be on the safe side.

<sup>Actually, just adding `\do\:` would be sufficient, but generic verbatim needs the others as well.</sup>

```
%%% must go before changing catcodes
\input epsf

%% something for French typography
\frenchspacing

\catcode`\:=\active
\catcode`\;=\active
\catcode`\?=\active
\catcode`\!=\active

\def;{\unskip\thinspace\string;}
\def?{\unskip\thinspace\string?}
\def!{\unskip\thinspace\string!}
\def:{\unskip~\string:}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\dospecials\expandafter{%
  \dospecials\do\:\do\;\do\?\do\!%
}

%%% the document

a; b a ; b

a! a? a ! a ?

a: b a : b

\centerline{\epsfbox{tryepsf.1}}

\bye
```

[image]

As far as I know, the spaces around the colon should be equal, contrary to what happens for other punctuation, so I have changed the definition accordingly. I also added `\unskip` to all definitions, just in case users type spaces in front of punctuation by force of habit.

Comment: As far as I know, : is a "ponctuation double" so the same rule apply as for the other ones. Bu anyway, thanks for the dospecials!